# Extracting certain header's data from CSV file, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

C.N: company names
C.N2: company names

```
C.N    Cmp Cmp  Cmp  Cmp   Cmp Cmp Cmp  
C.N2   IGN IGT  IGA        IGB IGB                
php     12  12   11   35     5   1   6 
java    12  12   11   35     5   1   6 
react   100 100 100   35   100  100  6  
IOS     12  12   11   35     5   1   6 
python  12  12   11   35     5   1   6 
JSX     12  12   11   35     5   1   6
```

I have CSV file in this structure. Trying to parse the 100's and C.N

```
import csv

take = ["IGN","IGT", "IGB"]

with open("datas.csv", "r") as Data:
    Reader = csv.reader(Data)

    for line in Reader:
        if line[0] == "IOS":
            break
        print(line)
```

How can I just select React datas? But if it include C.N 2, I mean is it possible to select certain Header's certain data? and send it to other CSV file?

Expected out put is

```
Cmp   Cmp   Cmp      Cmp   Cmp        Cmp    Cmp  Cmp
100   100   100      100   100        100   100  100
```

As you see I skipped the empty cells and their datas

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: I updated the question with the expected output @Rakesh

Comment: I am just saying that, I want the data which is under  IGN,  IGT,  IGA, IGB, IGN, if there is empty cell in the header then I don't want to parse the the data under that. @SpghttCd

Comment: How many header is coming, that's not important actually. Just trying to parse all header 1's and  not empty header 2's data. @SpghttCd

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I understand you now. The Header 1 is too 11, I just forget the write it. I am updating the question now. I am sorry. @SpghttCd

Comment: You have 8 `cmp` and 9 `100`

Comment: i updated the question i think it makes more sense now.

Comment: I misunderstood csv file first. Sorry, about that. Now updated the orginal structure. @SpghttCd

Comment: Nope, just try to show it easily it's not include | in the file. @SpghttCd

Comment: I understand now, it's okay now. No decoration. thank you for advise. @SpghttCd

Comment: The point is: if you want to parse a text file, you need to know it's structure - and there are plenty of ways to structure tabular data in a text file. One possibility is to separate columns with a special separator character, like `,` or `;` for example. But the separator can also be invisible like `space` or `tab`. Another possibility e.g. is to use no separator, but to structure the rows in a way that every columns gets the same number of characters, this is called "fixed-width-file". So it is crucial to first, before doing anything else, independent of which tool you'll use for importing:

Comment: Check, which kind of structure you're dealing with.

Comment: So that's the reason why I ask you to check, if there are tabulators between the columns: this way you could easily parse the columns of header line two although there are empty cells. But I can't see it from here. It could perhaps also be a fixed-width-file, but the rightmost `100` does not fit into this structure, it's one character too far on the right side...

Comment: Oh you are right about that. I fixed the 100 issue. Check it again please. Now How can I parse it? Any answer idea? @SpghttCd

Comment: well, no, I meant in terms of the definition of a fixed-width-file, the rightmost `100` does not fit perfectly under its `Cmp` and `IGB` headers, it is one space to far on the right. I can _guess_ that this is because you did not copy paste the whole csv-file as one monolithic block, but corrected manually around... Please do us the favour: delete the whole block, copy the complete content of the csv-file and paste it in one action into this post. No editing, no row- or value-wise optimizing or anything.

Comment: Sir, it's very Japanese you don't understand if I paste it or not. this is quite understandable. I think.

Comment: Sorry, now _I_ don't understand a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always advised people to go for pandas when parsing excel files. Load them all into a dataframe and it becomes a whole lot easier to work with.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0) # Creates a dataframe out of your csv. Your C.N row will be your header row but that's fine since it fits nicely into the output that you need
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.iloc[0].isnull()]._data)  # Drop null columns
df_out = df.loc['react'] # Filters only for the desired row

# Next 2 lines to drop the C.N column to get the desired final output
df_out.reset_index()
df_out = df_out.drop(columns=['C.N']) # Drops the C.N column
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186511/discussion-between-barbie-and-kerwei).

Answer (score 0):

***Final Edit:***

---

**Problem description**

After you posted a portion of the *real* data file (https://imgur.com/a/AgRMC8S),
[image]
both the problem and the solution become immediately clear:

Your csv-file is a simple, perfectly standard-aligned csv file with commas as separators (see marks in blue), so that even empty cells can easily be handled, because they are just two directly consecutive commas (see marks in red).
*I.e. your sample data has nothing to do with your real data...*
A correct equivalent sample data file would have been

```
C.N,Cmp,Cmp,Cmp,Cmp,Cmp,Cmp,Cmp
C.N2,IGN,IGT,IGA,,IGB,IGB,
php,12,12,11,35,5,1,6 
java,12,12,11,35,5,1,6 
react,100,100,100,35,100,100,6
IOS,12,12,11,35,5,1,6 
python,12,12,11,35,5,1,6 
JSX,12,12,11,35,5,1,6
```

This is the reason why @kerwei's pandas solution based on simple `pd.read_csv` with comma as default separator worked for you although there was not a single comma in the sample csv data.

---

**Answer to the correctly asked question**

In **your code** snippet, you print every line *until* you reach the line after the one you're interested in.
But you should print nothing *except* you reach the line you're intrested in:

```
import csv

with open("datas.csv", "r") as Data:
    Reader = csv.reader(Data)

    for line in Reader:
        if line[0] == "react":
            print(line)
            break
```

---

However, your additional requirement to filter the rows is inded much more elegantly solved with pandas, so my **pandas approach** would be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
df_r = df.loc[['C.N2', 'react'], ~df.loc['C.N2'].isna()]

#       Cmp Cmp.1 Cmp.2 Cmp.4 Cmp.5
#C.N                               
#C.N2   IGN   IGT   IGA   IGB   IGB
#react  100   100   100   100   100
```

Writing only the data rows of this result (df without header and index) to another csv file is just as easy:

```
df_r.to_csv('react.csv', header=False, index=False)

#IGN,IGT,IGA,IGB,IGB
#100,100,100,100,100
```

---

But of course you *can* do it **without external libraries**, too

```
with open(filename) as f:
    next(f)
    header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
    drop_idx = [i for i, h in enumerate(header) if not h]
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('react'):
            data = line.strip().split(',')
            break

for i in drop_idx[::-1]:
    header.pop(i)
    data.pop(i)
with open('react.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(','.join(header[1:]) + '\n')
    f.write(','.join(data[1:]))
```

---

and finally one request for future questions: please try  in terms of [[mcve]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to simplify your problem in a way, that the important properties of your real problem don't get lost, that would save a lot of time.

Comment: First, thank you taking care of me. Maybe I should just show the real file. the yellow places are what I want to parse https://imgur.com/a/GH4Dm0Z could you check it out. is It possible?

Comment: So it is originally _not_ a csv-file? Is it an Excel-file? Then you could indeed import directly from the `xls` like in @kerwei's _first_ solution. However, again some important questions: __1__. In my experience, Excel exports to csv by default with `,`or `;`, as separator, not with a blank space. Changing that would help here. __2.__ Was it _your_ decision to leave a few cells completely blank? I ask because the other solution would be to insert e.g. `-` or `NA` or sth. instead of nothing. You see: in the end it's all about making it possible to differ between separators and blank cells.

Comment: okay 1. it's csv file. 2. it's not my decision. That's why I need to parse it this way. And create an other file with parsed data....

Comment: okay, then how did you make the screenshot you posted on imgur? Did you simply open it with excel?

Comment: yep, that's right.

Comment: Then there _must_ be a separator which is different from the blank cells... Do you know the mode of some texteditors, where control characters are displayed? Do you have e.g. `Notepad++`? But perhaps it works with MS Word, too...

Comment: I am using mac with Numbers. But the file I get csv. So do I need to use separator on blank space?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I don't know mac, but I found that there is a text editor called `TextEdit` included in MacOS. Could you please open the csv in `TextEdit`? And then switch on the control character visible mode - it should be a button in the upper left, looks like some strange stretched greek letter `pi`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186481/discussion-between-barbie-and-spghttcd).

Comment: Sorry, chat is "access denied" on my side... We can delete 90% of this afterwards...:)

Comment: Haha, no problem. Thank you for helping me out. But what is this gonna help I don't understand really... :)

Comment: It will hopefully show us directly what characters are used as separators in your file. Look at the screenshot in my edit above: you can clearly differ between blank spaces and tabs, because the former are orange dots and the latter orange arrows. if you open the csv-file in `TextEdit` and switch on this mode, we'll see. And _then_ we're able to set the correct parameters for importing the file via python - no matter with which library.

Comment: The longer I think about it, the more I'm sure it's `tab`separated - or at least would kindly ask you to test: `df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\t', index_col=0)`

Comment: it returns the first col.

Comment: So it does _not_ work, right? It throws the whole rows into one column...? What about the hidden characters? Did you have a look at the file via `TextEdit`?

Comment: I tried kerwei's code, it dump it two rows but there was empty cell's data in it... is it really imposibble to do this? what i am trying to achive here. take those datas, and copy it another csv file... By the way textEdit did't work or I couldn't make it.

Comment: not the time to give up yet... What exactly do you mean by "kerwsei's code" - the first one based on `pd.ExcelFile`?

Comment: in the kerwei's answer. https://imgur.com/a/GR6H6wK

Comment: Okay, I found a way. the orjinal csv file always some pattern. That's why is export it csv file the result. After that I mark the unwanted cells and delete those and make another csv file...? is it possible to delete cells?

Comment: Ah, understand. In my opinion, it's too early for trying to use any importer function without knowing the separator...

Comment: @Barbie Actually, it'll be really helpful if you run up to Line 3 and then dump out the df variable

Comment: @Barbie see my edit, please try the latest code. The result should give the right hints for the separator.

Comment: I tried it and give me this. https://imgur.com/a/AgRMC8S by the wa thank you for helping me out with @kerwei . Also i am using Pycharm... Which button you talking about?